# Use multiple forms in one view and submit them to several different tables

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-core

I have view that in this view, I want to pass some models to it. I'm passing models like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_Project", Model.AllProjects)
 @Html.Partial("_Blog", Model.AllBlog)
 @Html.Partial("_Comment", Model.AllComments)
```

this view feeds on a viewModel (HomeMultiViewModel) that contains some models like this:

```
 public class HomeMultiViewModel
    {
        public List<Project> AllProjects { get; set; }
        public List<Blog> AllBlog { get; set; }
        public List<Blog> SearchInBlog { get; set; }
        public List<Costumer> AllCostumers { get; set; }
        public List<Comments> AllComments { get; set; }

    }
```

Except these, I have 2 forms in this view that the values of one them should be sent to a model named `ContactYou`, and the values of another one should be send to a model names `advise`.

This is first form in my view:

```
<form class="UswithYouForm">
    <input type="tel" class="UswithYouFormInput" placeholder="Phone number.." />
    <button type="submit" class="UswithYouFormButtom">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

This is the second for in that view:

```
<form class="adviseForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" />
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" />
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
    <button class="slide__text-link">Send your request!</button>
</form>
```

And at last this is my controller for that view:

```
namespace Atawin.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _context = context;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            HomeMultiViewModel model = new HomeMultiViewModel();
            model.AllProjects = (from p in _context.projects select p).ToList();
            model.AllBlog = (from b in _context.blogs select b).ToList();
            model.AllCostumers = (from c in _context.costumers select c).ToList();
            model.AllComments = (from com in _context.comments select com).ToList();
            ViewBag.RootPath = "/upload/Norm/";
            return View(model);
        }

        public IActionResult Search(string searchedTxt)
        {
            HomeMultiViewModel model = new HomeMultiViewModel();
            model.AllBlog = (from b in _context.blogs select b).ToList();
            model.AllCostumers = (from c in _context.costumers select c).ToList();
            model.SearchInBlog = (from sb in _context.blogs where sb.Title.Contains(searchedTxt) orderby sb.Id descending select sb).Take(15).ToList();
            ViewBag.RootPath = "/upload/Norm/";
            ViewBag.SearchedWords = searchedTxt;
            return View(model);
        }

        // i want an action here to solve my problem

    }
}
```

I actually reed the questions like this on the whole websites, but I can't solve my problem. If you need more to answer this question tell me so I'll send theme to you.

Comment: Can't anyone help me???

Comment: What actually do you need to accomplish?

Comment: You want to submit both forms at the same time but route them to different controller actions? If that's the case, not gonna happen. (Or it might work if you go real dirty, but I'm sure that the C# developers had that in mind.) Rethink your logic a little bit. Why not create 1 form that holds all the fields and then when you're submitting your form, you can then split the model again in the controller and call different controller methods based on that.